# how to revert a binary dump file?

Tags: linux, binary, dump

a binary dump file is like a hex dump file except that it is in binary form instead of hex

now I've got a binary dump file looks like this:

```
01101110 01101100 01000001 01000001 01000001 00101011 00110001 01011010
01001000 00110100 01110011 01001001 01000001 01000011 01001010 01001011
...
```

and I know the original file was a normal text file, so how can I revert or say recover it from the dump file?

Comment: it's just an example and the language of the original file is not english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use python, something like this:

```
import re
f = open('dump', 'r')
token= re.split(r'[ \n]', f.read())
map (lambda (t):  chr(int(t, 2)), token)
```

Comment: I don't know python and the code doesn't work on my machine (re is not defined), but I've got your point and wrote a php script to do the same thing

Comment: @chrisyue great, if you want the python code to work too, `import re` first

Answer (score 0):

based on: http://www.unix.com/programming/8680-binary-text-format-conversion.html

sounds like `uuencode` is your friend :)
I checked it and on my Fedora 17 package is called: `perl-Convert-UU`